# Issue in converting SVG images into Data URI using Grunticon

Tags: svg, gruntjs, data-uri

When I'm converting my svg and png images into data uris through grunticon, the code generated for pngs are working fine but the svg images are not getting rendered (Error:Failed to load the given URL). The path to the file is correct what could have gone wrong?

SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><!DOCTYPE svg  PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN'  'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'><svg enable-background="new 0 0 48 48" height="48px" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="48px" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><g id="Expanded"><g><g><path d="M43,48H29c-0.553,0-1-0.448-1-1V1c0-0.552,0.447-1,1-1h14c0.553,0,1,0.448,1,1v46C44,47.552,43.553,48,43,48z M30,46h12     V2H30V46z"/></g><g><rect height="2" width="5" x="29" y="8"/></g><g><rect height="2" width="5" x="29" y="14"/></g><g><rect height="2" width="5" x="29" y="20"/></g><g><rect height="2" width="5" x="29" y="26"/></g><g><rect height="2" width="5" x="29" y="32"/></g><g><rect height="2" width="5" x="29" y="38"/></g><g><path d="M15,46h-4c-2.757,0-5-2.243-5-5V12c0-0.197,0.059-0.391,0.168-0.555l6-9c0.371-0.557,1.293-0.557,1.664,0l6,9     C19.941,11.609,20,11.803,20,12v29C20,43.757,17.757,46,15,46z M8,12.303V41c0,1.654,1.346,3,3,3h4c1.654,0,3-1.346,3-3V12.303     l-5-7.5L8,12.303z"/></g><g><path d="M19,40H7c-0.553,0-1-0.448-1-1s0.447-1,1-1h12c0.553,0,1,0.448,1,1S19.553,40,19,40z"/></g><g><path d="M19,36H7c-0.553,0-1-0.448-1-1s0.447-1,1-1h12c0.553,0,1,0.448,1,1S19.553,36,19,36z"/></g><g><path d="M11,36c-0.553,0-1-0.448-1-1V16c0-0.552,0.447-1,1-1s1,0.448,1,1v19C12,35.552,11.553,36,11,36z"/></g><g><path d="M15,36c-0.553,0-1-0.448-1-1V16c0-0.552,0.447-1,1-1s1,0.448,1,1v19C16,35.552,15.553,36,15,36z"/></g><g><rect height="2" width="6" x="10" y="7"/></g><g><path d="M10,17c-2.206,0-4-1.794-4-4c0-0.552,0.447-1,1-1s1,0.448,1,1c0,1.103,0.897,2,2,2s2-0.897,2-2c0-0.552,0.447-1,1-1     s1,0.448,1,1C14,15.206,12.206,17,10,17z"/></g><g><path d="M16,17c-2.206,0-4-1.794-4-4c0-0.552,0.447-1,1-1s1,0.448,1,1c0,1.103,0.897,2,2,2s2-0.897,2-2c0-0.552,0.447-1,1-1     s1,0.448,1,1C20,15.206,18.206,17,16,17z"/></g></g></g></svg>
```

Generated Data uri:

```
.icon-1 { background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20%3F%3E%3C!DOCTYPE%20svg%20%20PUBLIC%20%5Ci-%2F%2FW3C%2F%2FDTD%20SVG%201.1%2F%2FEN%5Ci%20%20%5Cihttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FGraphics%2FSVG%2F1.1%2FDTD%2Fsvg11.dtd%5Ci%3E%3Csvg%20enable-background%3D%22new%200%200%2048%2048%22%20height%3D%2248px%22%20version%3D%221.1%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2048%2048%22%20width%3D%2248px%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22Expanded%22%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M43%2C48H29c-0.553%2C0-1-0.448-1-1V1c0-0.552%2C0.447-1%2C1-1h14c0.553%2C0%2C1%2C0.448%2C1%2C1v46C44%2C47.552%2C43.553%2C48%2C43%2C48z%20M30%2C46h12%20%20%20%20%20V2H30V46z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3Crect%20height%3D%222%22%20width%3D%225%22%20x%3D%2229%22%20y%3D%228%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3Crect%20height%3D%222%22%20width%3D%225%22%20x%3D%2229%22%20y%3D%2214%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3Crect%20height%3D%222%22%20width%3D%225%22%20x%3D%2229%22%20y%3D%2220%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3Crect%20height%3D%222%22%20width%3D%225%22%20x%3D%2229%22%20y%3D%2226%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3Crect%20height%3D%222%22%20width%3D%225%22%20x%3D%2229%22%20y%3D%2232%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3Crect%20height%3D%222%22%20width%3D%225%22%20x%3D%2229%22%20y%3D%2238%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M15%2C46h-4c-2.757%2C0-5-2.243-5-5V12c0-0.197%2C0.059-0.391%2C0.168-0.555l6-9c0.371-0.557%2C1.293-0.557%2C1.664%2C0l6%2C9%20%20%20%20%20C19.941%2C11.609%2C20%2C11.803%2C20%2C12v29C20%2C43.757%2C17.757%2C46%2C15%2C46z%20M8%2C12.303V41c0%2C1.654%2C1.346%2C3%2C3%2C3h4c1.654%2C0%2C3-1.346%2C3-3V12.303%20%20%20%20%20l-5-7.5L8%2C12.303z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M19%2C40H7c-0.553%2C0-1-0.448-1-1s0.447-1%2C1-1h12c0.553%2C0%2C1%2C0.448%2C1%2C1S19.553%2C40%2C19%2C40z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M19%2C36H7c-0.553%2C0-1-0.448-1-1s0.447-1%2C1-1h12c0.553%2C0%2C1%2C0.448%2C1%2C1S19.553%2C36%2C19%2C36z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M11%2C36c-0.553%2C0-1-0.448-1-1V16c0-0.552%2C0.447-1%2C1-1s1%2C0.448%2C1%2C1v19C12%2C35.552%2C11.553%2C36%2C11%2C36z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M15%2C36c-0.553%2C0-1-0.448-1-1V16c0-0.552%2C0.447-1%2C1-1s1%2C0.448%2C1%2C1v19C16%2C35.552%2C15.553%2C36%2C15%2C36z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3Crect%20height%3D%222%22%20width%3D%226%22%20x%3D%2210%22%20y%3D%227%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M10%2C17c-2.206%2C0-4-1.794-4-4c0-0.552%2C0.447-1%2C1-1s1%2C0.448%2C1%2C1c0%2C1.103%2C0.897%2C2%2C2%2C2s2-0.897%2C2-2c0-0.552%2C0.447-1%2C1-1%20%20%20%20%20s1%2C0.448%2C1%2C1C14%2C15.206%2C12.206%2C17%2C10%2C17z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M16%2C17c-2.206%2C0-4-1.794-4-4c0-0.552%2C0.447-1%2C1-1s1%2C0.448%2C1%2C1c0%2C1.103%2C0.897%2C2%2C2%2C2s2-0.897%2C2-2c0-0.552%2C0.447-1%2C1-1%20%20%20%20%20s1%2C0.448%2C1%2C1C20%2C15.206%2C18.206%2C17%2C16%2C17z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E'); background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

Comment: any code samples you can provide?

Comment: Does the SVG code you use work as a stand-alone SVG file?  I.e., is it valid xml with all the namespace prefixes declared?  Is the correct file type declared?  Are there any special characters?  Beyond that, we really need to see before-and-after code (i.e., the original SVG code plus the data URI code) to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @AmeliaBR The SVG files are working f9 (stand-alone). I've added i/p and o/p in my question look if that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<!DOCTYPE svg  PUBLIC \i-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN\i  \ihttp://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd\i>`

This declaration contains `\i` which isn't valid. Change to `"` and you'll get the "pencil with ruler" icon.

In another words, change `%5Ci` to `%22`